# Generating polygons from points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I made this polygon by creating a scratch layer and tracing out the outside points (see image below) grouping the points nearest to each other.

[image]

However, tracing out the points will take time for me, I tried different methods to generate polygon automatically, but they don't look promising to me.

This is by clustering then concave hull with threshold = 0.01
close but still not what result that I want.
[image]

This is by buffer : rectangular and dissolve. The edges are too sharp and I have to regularly change the "distance" to fit that there will be no holes inside.

[image]

This is from cluster, then minimum bounding geometry.

[image]

Comment: The block in the lower left can make trouble for algorithms. Could you consider separating that from the rest of the data?

Comment: Did you try Smooth tool?

Comment: Try really fine tuning the alpha parameter of Concave hull. I tried on a similar point data set and 0.025 was to small but 0.03 gave a good result

Answer (score 4):

You can use Spatialite and create a Virtual Layer:

First the query will cross join all points to themselves if there is a point within 45 meters of another and create lines between them:

[image]

and then polygonize and unary union the polygons:
[image]

You need a column named id with unique values integer values, and replace points with the name of your point layer. Adjust 45 m to just include the closest 8 points, see last screenshot.

```
select a.id, b.id, st_UnaryUnion(polygonize(makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry))) as geometry
from points a
join points b
on ptdistwithin(a.geometry, b.geometry, 45)
and a.id<b.id
```

[image]

Comment: This is way too advance for my level. Although. I tried and gave me an error : Error executing SQL:
Error executing SQL select a.id, b.id, st_UnaryUnion(polygonize(makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry))) as geometry from points a join points b on ptdistwithin(a.geometry, b.geometry, 45) and a.id<b.id: There was an error opening GPKG dbname='file:///C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/20230327_CDC_BOKA-copy.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=Easting&yField=Northing&crs=USER:100000&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'!
Execution failed after 0.06 seconds

Comment: If your layer is a delimited text layer I suggest you export it to a proper point layer in shapefile or geopackage format

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the "Cluster DBSCAN" tool, which assign a cluster number to each point within a giving distance of each other.

Then, you can use "minimum bounding geometry",specifying the ID_CLUSTER attribute created with the cluster DBScan to regroup entities.

Comment: Thanks for this , however in "min bounding geom' it did not work

Comment: I changed the above applying your suggestions. concave hull is the closest I think .. but is there other options for this? thank you very much

Comment: I don't see other options in this tool.                                                                             
An other way, could be to apply a Buffer on your Cluster DBScan result ; and then Dissolve the layer by joining on the CLUSTER_ID attribute... and try different options with simplify tools.